# How to get GCC to give an error-message when a structure initialization does not match the structure-type definition?

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures

I have a problem of **gcc** not generating an error when a structure's initialization does not match it's structure-type definition -- even when the compiler is supposedly running in the most nit-picky mode possible.

The following command is invoked by **make** in a package that was configured in what I call "developer mode" -- that being that an option is added so that the compiler will be as nit-picky and squeamish as possible - thereby letting the developer know that there is something that needs to be fixed in the code.

```
gcc -Wall -Qunused-arguments -Werror -I./libchbclib/inc -I/Users/red_angel/chorebox_sys/include -c -o tmp/lchbclib/chbclib_strq_new.o ./libchbclib/csrc/chbclib_strq_new.c
```

It (at the moment) does all the compiling and building without error including this following block quote ....

```
static chbclib_strq_cl st_mainclass =
{
  st_meth_add // m_add
};
```

... which references the following structure in an include file elsewhere in the package ....

```
typedef struct chbclib_strq_cl {
  bool (*m_add) ( void  *srf_aa, char *rg_a );
  // Adds a new string to the queue. Failure to do so is a
  // fatal-error to the program if the objects 'erat' value
  // is 0. Other wise, the boolean return value will let
  // the calling program know whether or not the operation
  // was a success.
} chbclib_strq_cl;
```

Of course, so far, it's okay that the thing builds without error. However, when I make the following change to the include-file, it *should* generate an error ----

```
typedef struct chbclib_strq_cl {
  bool (*m_add) ( void  *srf_aa, char *rg_a );
  // Adds a new string to the queue. Failure to do so is a
  // fatal-error to the program if the objects 'erat' value
  // is 0. Other wise, the boolean return value will let
  // the calling program know whether or not the operation
  // was a success.

  bool (*m_axd) ( void  *srf_aa, char *rg_a );
  // Adding this to the structure-type definition should produce
  // an error ---- but it doesn't.

} chbclib_strq_cl;
```

--- But for some reason, it *still* does not generate an error.

Is there any way that I can force the **gcc** compiler to generate an error if a structure's initialization does not match the structure-type definition? Thanks.

Of course --- some of you might wonder why I am complaining of an error-message *not* being present. The answer is this --- when I build the package in non-developer mode, I'm okay with the error not being there. However, I implemented the option of developer-mode *specifically* because I want to be alerted as much as possible to anything that is a problem in my code.

In this case, the example is that if I have a structure-type that has multiple structures of that type initialized at different parts of the program, and I add a field (or make any other change) to that structure-type, I will need to also update the code at every other place in the program where a structure of that type is initialized. However, what if I "miss a spot" in that updating? If that happens, I am counting on an error-message to alert me.

So --- how can I get **gcc** to fulfill this important need when I configure the package in developer-mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the -Wmissing-field-initializers option.

It's enabled by default when -Wextra is used.

From the gcc version 4.8.2 manpage:

> ```
>    -Wmissing-field-initializers
>        Warn if a structure's initializer has some fields missing.  For example, the following code causes such a warning, because "x.h" is implicitly zero:
>                struct s { int f, g, h; };
>                struct s x = { 3, 4 };
>        This option does not warn about designated initializers, so the following modification
>        does not trigger a warning:
>                struct s { int f, g, h; };
>                struct s x = { .f = 3, .g = 4 };
>        This warning is included in -Wextra.  To get other -Wextra warnings without this one,
>        use -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers.
> ```

Clang will trigger warnings much more frequently than GCC when this option is used. If GCC isn't issuing a warning, try with Clang to see if something changes.

With gcc version 4.8.2 there are some cases that the warning isn't triggered (for example, when only the first field is initialized to zero), but also note that depending of what standard you're using to compile your code, uninitialized structure fields ahead of the first structure field may be acceptable as valid C.

Comment: Okay ----- I will try it and get back to you as soon as I have. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) The -Wextra option has saved the day. :-)